# Sharepoint Blog Category view - Pagination issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Folks, I am facing a rather strange issue. In my Sharepoint Blog, I am not able to view more than 10 posts when I click on the Category filter page.

The page only shows the latest 10 posts and when I click on the pagination for the next 10, it simply says that "There are no posts in this category." I tried searching online and [some one had a solution to it too](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118043635/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/steveclements/archive/2009/01/06/sharepoint--blog-category-view-not-filtered-by-category-again.aspx), but that is with the Query String (URL) Filter which is not available in MOSS2007 Standard edition...

How can I get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the net for the Sharepoint Blog Category Pagination issue... and it works for me.  [Thanks to this blog](http://vutla.blogspot.com/2008/12/workarounds-for-bugs-on-sharepoint-v3.html)

All you need to do is copy paste the following script. Go to the blog/category/Category.aspx and add a Content Editior Web Part. Then go to Source Editor and Copy Paste the following CODE.

You can also make sure to HIDE the Webpart so that its not visible / annoying to others by ticking Hidden under Layout option.

```
<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" > 
function changeLink(){
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var Category = JSRequest.QueryString["Name"];
var parent;
var child;
for (var counter =0; counter < 100; counter++){
var elementId = 'bottomPagingCellWPQ'+ counter;
if (document.getElementById(elementId)){ 
parent = document.getElementById(elementId);
child = parent.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
if (child.childNodes.length > 0){
for (var y = 0; y < child.childNodes.length; y++ ){
if(child.childNodes[y].childNodes){ 
if(child.childNodes[y].childNodes[0].tagName){
theAnchorTag = child.childNodes[y].childNodes[0];
for( var x = 0; x < theAnchorTag.attributes.length; x++ ){
if( theAnchorTag.attributes[x].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'onclick' ){
var str = theAnchorTag.attributes[x].nodeValue;
str = str.replace( '?', '?Name=' + Category + '\\u0026');
theAnchorTag.attributes[x].nodeValue = str;
onclk = theAnchorTag.attributes[x].nodeValue;
theAnchorTag.onclick = new Function(onclk);
}
}
}
}
}
}
break;
}
}
}
addLoadEvent(changeLink);
function addLoadEvent(func) {
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
window.onload = func;
} 
else{
window.onload = function(){
if (oldonload) {oldonload();}
func();}
}
}
</script>
```